# Create link with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this Jquery code

```
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pav li a").click(function() {
            $(".srvctext").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='loading2.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
            $("#pav li a").css('color','#656565');
            $(this).css('color','#3ca5d4');
            $.ajax({ 
                url: this.href, 
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".srvctext").empty().append(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
</script>
  </head>
```

and this HTML

```
  <div class="srvclinksholder">
    <h4> Our Services </h4>

        <ul id="pav">
            <li><a href="pages/page_1.html"  id="mostPopular">Technical Infrastructure Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/page_2.html"  id="mostPopular">Email Exchange Service (Messaging)</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/page_3.html"  id="mostPopular">Firewall Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/page_4.html"  id="mostPopular">Security and Antivirus Service</a></li>
....
```

I want to be able create a link from another page to one of these pages, I think I have to use # somehow just unsure. So if I have `<a href="service/pages/page_4.html">` service being the page name that will not obviously work. Maybe something like this `<a href="service.html#pages/page_4.html">`

What changes do I have to make to achieve this?

Comment: Just so you know, you can't use the same value for id repeatedly, even if the browser or libraries tolerate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/LxreN/3/

Basically you are going to be changing the html of the other div.

```
$(".srvctext").html("<div id='loading'><img src='loading2.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
```

with the following the in success, there isn't a need to empty everytime since that is causing 2 DOM accesses everytime, which IE doesn't handle well.

```
    success: function(html) {
        $(".srvctext").html(html);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I changed my code to yours. How would I link to a specific page is what I'm asking? so if I want to go directly to pages/page_1.html from my home page. e.g. <a href="service.php/pages/page_1.html">more</a>. I click more and it should go to page pages/page_1.html. My links are all Jquery, so on my URL nothing shows, though the code does work. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm very confused on what you are directly wanting.  Please edit my jsfiddle to be more like what you are wanting and then update it.  I'd be more than happy to take another look at it.  Also I don't understand why the link you described isn't working, it appears you are pulling all your content from an ajax call. Then you are loading it into another div.  Are you wanting a link that actually transfers your html location?  If so, an <a href> would work just fine, you'd need to not bind to the .click instead just make a function and add <a href="" onclick="functionName()">blah</a> let me know.

Comment: I may have described the matter wrongly. The best way I can phrase it is, how can I get to this jquery (ready loaded) section page_4.html from another page (e.g. Home). The code snippet I posted is from service.php. So I make a link on my Home page something like href="******">more</a>. I click it and goes to service.php with the div for page_4 ready loaded.

Comment: updated answer, basically make the service except the page you want to get the html from then load it like the new answer. http://jsfiddle.net/LxreN/3/